# Increasing the WordPress upload file size in Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Looking for some help with Google Cloud which I am learning.

I have got as far finishing a WordPress install, but I need to change the 'Maximum File Upload Size' from the standard 2mb.

I have followed many tutorials online and can actually get into and changed the php.ini file to the size I want, but I can save the file to save and I get 'Permission denied.'

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to edit the php.ini with admin permissions.

Use Sudo to edit the file

I believe GC instances allow you to type:

```
sudo -s
```

To get root privileges.

Comment: No problem, we’ve all been there! Can you accept the answer 

Answer (score 0):

Can I know how you managed to install wordpress ? Did you use the cloud manager? I am trying to do it manually. Im not able to do it.

Coming to your question you can increase the upload limit by editing the php.ini file with a text editor of you choice.

```
sudo nano 'path to php.ini file'
```

After opening the file add these line to the file. You can change the values after '=' to suit your requirements.

`upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
max_execution_time = 300`